# Qt 4.8: Layout: Hide widgets if no more space available

Tags: qt, layout

My application window can be resized to zero-size. I do not want to restrict the minimum window size. There are several widgets (QLineEdits, QLabels, QPushButtons) layoutet by a HBoxLayout.

At first, all widgets in the HBoxLayout were resized without respecting their sizeHint when the window was very small.
Then I used setFixedSize(sizeHint) on them. Now they do not get shrunk below their sizeHint, but instead they start overlapping when the window is very small.

What I want is what Thunderbird does (screenshots attached):
It smoothly hides the widgets by moving them out of the window border. Their size is unchanged.

How can I achieve that with the Qt Layouting system?

```
my application: normal window
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLgLy.png

my application: small window
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIhhs.png

Thunderbird: normal window    
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYJ83.png

Thunderbird: small window
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyQou.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your widgets into a QScrollArea
2. Set the vertical and horizontal scroll bar policy's to AlwaysOff
3. Layout your Scroll area as you wish

Done & done

Comment: Thank you, that was just the kind of solution I was looking for, since it does not involve writing custom layouting/resizing code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's not what you want but consider this:
Put your all stuff in a widget (named just 'widget' here), do not put this 'widget' into any layout just leave it free and add this event function to your window class:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event){
   ui->widget->move(QPoint(event->size().width()-ui->widget->width()-20,ui->widget->y()));
   QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

it works!